# Receiving null parameters from request in JSP file when are being sent

Tags: ajax, jsp, request

I've a JSP app. It uploads a file, but to do so the user has to authenticate using a name and a password. So my JSP file starts with:

```
//0.2.- We get the password
String password = (String) request.getParameter("pass"); // -> This returns NULL
//0.3.- We get the "uvus"
String uvus = (String) request.getParameter("uvus"); //-> This also returns NULL

//More code
```

So I'm trying to know **why am I getting null from those variables**.

I went to the form I was uploading, and look for the data that was being sent. Using Firefox Debug Tools, I saw:

[image: Example of data]

So in fact, it was being sent.

As additional info, I'm building the request like this:

```
var pUvus = document.getElementById("uvus").value;
var pPassword = document.getElementById("pass").value;

var file = document.getElementById("userFile");

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
formData.append("uvus", pUvus);
formData.append("pass", pPassword);

xmlhttp.open("POST","uploadFile.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

At last, I would like to say that I can get vars from application object in the same JSP with no errors, and have received in another pair of JSP files vars at request object without more problems, so I think my fault should be in the way I'm building the request in Ajax, but I've no more clue about that...

Anyone can guide me?

Thanks for your help

**Update**: @rickz asked for how do I get the file and parse the request (what is done after my problem, trying to get the objects from the request scope):

```
List items;
items = servlet_up.parseRequest(request);

for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
{

  FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(i);

  if (! item.isFormField())
  {
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the request on the server?  How do you get the file?

Comment: I'm updating to give you it, but I don't see the relation between it (how i get the file) with the problem, since the it's done later, and the problem arrives when trying to get directly objects from the request object =S

Comment: Looking at your update, I am guessing that you are sending a multipart request and you are using  org.apache.commons.fileupload   If that is the case, then  it would explain why request.getParameter()  doesn't work.  You should be using  something like                        if(item.isFormField()){
                                          pass = item.getFieldName();   }   You can find lots of examples on this site. Or look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: I'm trying to do it like you say @rickz, will report progress when achieve to try this way. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! Please put it as an answer to validate it rickz! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.getParameter() won't work for a multipart/form-data request. 
If you are using  org.apache.commons.fileupload   then you should be using something like

```
if(item.isFormField()){
    name = item.getFieldName();
    ...                       
}
```